# ( DONE) Drug test question shouldn't be on hold, please reopen

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

This is a relevant and answerable question.

[Am I able to retake a Pre-employment Drug Screen?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/131282/am-i-able-to-retake-a-pre-employment-drug-screen/131284#131284)

Drug tests are not arbitrary, there are fixed and logical procedures for them which deal with attempts to dispute or retake the test in case of failure.

Comment: agreed.. VTRO cast.

Comment: In my locale permission to re-take a drug test could be completely company-specific (although extremely unlikely). I voted to reopen anyway.

Comment: Thanks it's open for more answers